# How to extract a substring until newline character from a string

Tags: java

I want to extract a substring.

when I pull the string its display like this in the console :

"**35.55**

₪

שקלים חדשים"

I need only the amount in the first row.

35.55\n₪\nשקלים חדשים

How can I do that in java please?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the split() method of the String class. It creates an array of strings. Then you can use first element of the array.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String original = "35.55\nHello\nWorld";
    System.out.println(original);
    String newstr[] = original.split("\n");
    System.out.println(newstr[0]);
}
```